# Querying Entities having self reference by JPA Specification

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `user` and `user_related_user` tables and `User` JPA Entity, 
having ManyToMany relation to itself.

```
@Entity @Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinTable(
    name = "user_related_user",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "related_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    }
  )
  public List<User> relatedUsers;
}
```

I want to get `User#relatedUsers` from `User#id` with JPA Specification.
So I have to union "this user's related users" and "some more users" dynamically.

in SQL, below query is required.

```
SELECT u.id FROM user u WHERE u.id IN (
  SELECT uru.related_user_id
  FROM user_related_user uru
  WHERE uru.user_id = ?
)
```

but I have no idea to do this with JPA Specification.
anyone knows better solution ?

current workaround is

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

  @Query("select ru.id from User u join u.relatedUsers ru where u.id = ?1")
  List<Long> findRelatedUserIds(Long id);
}

@Service @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService {

  @Autowired
  UserRepository repository;

  public List<Users> getSelectableUsers(Long id, /* and args */) {

    List<Long> currentRelatedUserIds = repository.findRelatedUserIds(id);

    Specification<User> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {

      return cb.or(
        root.get(User_.id).in(currentRelatedUserIds),
        /* generate some more predicates dynamically */
      );
    }

    return repository.findAll(spec);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to get a find users by related users.

My input data is

```
insert into user values(1);
insert into user values(2);
insert into user values(3);
insert into user values(4);
insert into user values(5);
insert into user values(6);
insert into user values(7);
insert into user values(8);
insert into user values(9);
insert into user values(10);

insert into user_related_user values(1,10);
insert into user_related_user values(1,9);
insert into user_related_user values(1,8);
insert into user_related_user values(2,7);
insert into user_related_user values(2,6);
insert into user_related_user values(2,5);
```

my repository is

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

  @Query("select ru.id from User u join u.relatedUsers ru where u.id = ?1")
  List<Long> findRelatedUserIds(Long id);

  List<User> findDistinctByRelatedUsersIdIn(List<Long> ids);
}
```

my test is

```
List<User> selectableUsers = userRepository.findDistinctByRelatedUsersIdIn(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{10l,9l,8l,7l,6l,5l}));
        assertEquals(2, selectableUsers.size());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but I need to build query dynamically. but your answer help to do this by JPA Specification.

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved this by using SubQuery like below.

```
public List<Users> getSelectableUsers(Long id, /* and args */) {

  Specification<User> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {

    query.distinct(true);

    Subquery<User> sq = query.subquery(User.class);
    Root<User> sqRoot = sq.from(User.class);
    sq.select(
      sqRoot.join(User_.relatedUsers)
    ).where(
      cb.equal(sqRoot.get(User_.id), id)
    );

    return cb.or(
      root.in(sq),
      // some more dynamic condition
    );
  }

  return repository.findAll(spec);
}
```